# Only allow IPv6 addresses in Apache

Tags: apache, ipv6, httpd.conf

How would I, in Apache, allow only IPv6 addresses to access my site?

This does not work:

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from ::/0
```

It says "The specified network mask is invalid."

Reference:

- https://www.ultratools.com/tools/ipv6CIDRToRangeResult?ipAddress=%3A%3A%2F0

Comment: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_access_compat.html order allow deny is deprecated use require

Comment: @ThomasSchäfer What should `order deny,allow` become, then? `Require all granted` or `Require all denied`?

Comment: ::/0 doesn't work, :: accepts IPv4 too, try 2000::/3

Comment: @ThomasSchäfer So, all global addresses start with 2000 through 3fff?

Comment: At least for the moment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from 2000::/3
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit `/etc/apache2/ports.conf` (or whereever the Apache `Listen` directives are in your particular configuration) and change:

```
Listen 80
...
Listen 443
```

to:

```
Listen [my-external-IPv6-address]:80
Listen [my-internal-IPv6-address]:80
Listen [any-other-IPv6-address]:80
Listen [::1]:80
...
Listen [my-external-IPv6-address]:443
Listen [my-internal-IPv6-address]:443
Listen [any-other-IPv6-address]:443
Listen [::1]:443
```

Of course, you have to use only as many lines, as you have actual IPv6 addresses assigned to your server. You usually do not need to specify those IPv6 link-local addresses, that begin with `fe80`. You can leave out the `Listen` directive on `::1`, if you do not need the ability to access your server via the IPv6 loopback interface.

The advantage of this solution: Ports 80 (HTTP) and 443 (HTTPS) become completely invisible on the IPv4 network. All these nasty port scanners out there won't find your apache anymore, as their connection attempts get immediately rejected by the operating system.

The disadvantage: If your IPv6 address(es) change(s), you have to update your Apache configuration.